# Redux Toolkit TS: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft<configSlice>'

Tags: redux-toolkit

I have a common dispatcher to update multiple states as shown below:

```
updateConfiguration: (state, action) => {
            const { type, payload } = action.payload
            const { dispatchKey, stateKey } = keyHelpers[type as keyof keyHelpersType]

            state[stateKey] = payload[dispatchKey]
        }
```

where `keyHelpers` is as shown below:

```
export const keyHelpers: keyHelpersType = {
    [actionTypes.addUser]: {
        dispatchKey: 'user',
        stateKey: 'user',
    }
```

When writing the dispatch logic in my reducer I am getting the following error in following line:

`state[stateKey] = payload[dispatchKey]`
Error:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft<configSlice>'`

I tried doing:

```
state[stateKey as keyof typeof state] = payload[dispatchKey]
```

but this didn't work as well throwing:

`Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`
Can someone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to add an `as const` assertion:

```
export const keyHelpers: keyHelpersType = {
    [actionTypes.addUser]: {
        dispatchKey: 'user',
        stateKey: 'user',
    }
} as const
```

That way it will not be `string`, but `"user"`.